# Ajax checking exam results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to javascript, but I really need to programm some ajax feature. I have a Joomla site with exams component. User can load exam, and it looks like this:

```
<fieldset id="question1">
<div class="js-marker">
    <div class="pull-right bu_marker_wrapper">
        <label data-original-title="Если вы хотите вернуться к вопросу позже, поставьте галочку - и в конце теста вы увидите все отмеченные вами вопросы." class="hasTooltip positionLeft" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">Отметьте, чтобы проверить позже
            <input class="js-marker" name="jform[responses][27476][response_marked]" value="1" data-marker-number="1" type="checkbox">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<h2>Вопрос 1</h2>
<div>
    <p>Работающий пенсионер настаивает на предоставлении ему дополнительного отпуска без сохранения содержания, сроком до двух недель. Правомерны ли его требования</p>
</div>
<div class="bu-question_input">

    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li>
            <label class="positionRight">
                <input class="problem mcq" name="jform[responses][27476][response_answers]" value="Работодатель на основании письменного заявления обязан предоставить ему отпуск" data-review-row-number="1" type="radio">Работодатель на основании письменного заявления обязан предоставить ему отпуск</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="positionRight">
                <input class="problem mcq" name="jform[responses][27476][response_answers]" value="Работодатель может такой отпуск работнику не предоставить" data-review-row-number="1" type="radio">Работодатель может такой отпуск работнику не предоставить</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="positionRight">
                <input class="problem mcq" name="jform[responses][27476][response_answers]" value="Вопрос решается в индивидуальном порядке, на усмотрение работодателя" data-review-row-number="1" type="radio">Вопрос решается в индивидуальном порядке, на усмотрение работодателя</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="spoiler-wrap">
    <div class="button spoiler-head folded">Показать подсказку</div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="spoiler-body">
        <p>Подсказка</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on.

I need to show the result of question right after clicking radio buttons. I made the ajax script and can get correct answer of question by ID in DB. It returning it in json format. Here's the code:

```
<input id="numtest" type="text">\
<div id="try">Попробовать</div>
<div id="result"></div>  
<script>
        function show(id)
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "../com_babelu_exams/exams/checkresult.php?id=" + id,
                datatype: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(jsondata){
                    var data = JSON.parse ( jsondata );
                    jQuery("#result").html(data.question_answers);
                }
            });

        }

        document.getElementById('try').onclick = function() {
            show(document.getElementById('numtest').value);
        }       
    </script>
```

It works, but I really don't know, how to make it showing the result by clicking radio buttons of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, If your form is loaded via ajax or your sections `.bu-question_input` are loaded via ajax you need to event delegate a little above the dom to listen to events.

```
$('.bu-question_input').on('click' , 'input[type=radio]', function(e){
  show($(e.target).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function on the desired radio button checked event

you have to mention the radio button id to call the function `show()` a specific radio button

```
<input class="problem mcq" id="radio_button" name="jform[responses][27476][response_answers]" value="Работодатель на основании письменного заявления обязан предоставить ему отпуск" data-review-row-number="1" type="radio">
```

then add the below script

```
 if($('#radio_button').is(':checked'))
 {
        show(this.id);
 }
```

if you want to call the function for all the radio button then use this

```
input[type="radio"]
```

the script can be

```
 $(function() {
        var $radioButtons = $('input[type="radio"]');
        $radioButtons.click(function() {       
               if($('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked'))
     { 
          show(this.id);
     }     
        });
    });
```

Comment: Fantastic! I think id of the question should be in fieldset. For example, <fieldset id="12">. So I'm trying to retrieve this id like this:

  `show(jQuery(this).parents("fieldset").id);`

and it doesn't work...